# Is there a way to create waffle charts using apache echarts

Tags: echarts, waffle-chart

I was trying to create a waffle chart using echarts3 library. Is there an existing method to do that? Any help is appreciated

[Waffle chart sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYQeM.png)

[image]